# Can I compare two fingerprints scanned from different fingerprint scanners?

Tags: fingerprint, fingerprintjs

Can I compare two fingerprints scanned from different fingerprint scanners? As I have read each fingerprint scanner uses its own method for scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use standard formats:

- ANSI / INCITS 378-2004  https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/image-group/resources/incits-standardized-biometric-data
- ISO 19794-2 /IEC with one  of these formats : FMR, FMC-NS, FMC-CS

Lot of fingerprint SDK support these formats

Comment: LaurentY Thank u so much ✌

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do. Every scanner supports giving the fingerprint template and the typical fingerprint image. With the help of the images, you can easily generate templates and compare with other fingerprints. For this, You need to implement your own Automatic Finger Identification algorithm or you have to use third party services such as

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)

If you rely on the template collected from various scanners, it is difficult to achieve what you need as not all the scanners provide the standard format templates. Some scanner do provide the ISO/ANSI standard formate template. But comparison algorithms are not available easily to implement.